# Algebraic variety geometrically reduced

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a problem with proposition 3.2.15 of Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves of Qing Liu: Let $X$ be an integral algebraic variety over $k$. If $X$ is geometrically reduced then $K(X)$ is a finite separable extension of a purely transcendental extension $k(T_1, \ldots , T_d)$.

First we proove that $K(X)$ is a finite extension of a purely transcendental extension $k(X_1,\ldots,X_r)$: I'm ok with that.
Let $L=k(X_1,\ldots,X_r)$ and $L_s$ the separable closure of $L$ is $K(X)$.

Then we proove that for all $b\in K(X)\setminus L_s$ such that $b^p\in L_s$, $L_s[b]$ is a finite separable extension of an (other) purely transcental extension $k(Y_1,\ldots,Y_q)$: I'm ok with that.

My problem and question come with the conclusion: "This imply the proposition by decomposing $K(X)/L_s$ into a sequence of purely inseparable extensions of degree $p = \operatorname{char}(k)$." I don't understand that.

I see that $K(X)=L_s[b_1,\ldots,b_m]$ so $L_s[b]$ would be a first step for induction? But for that I need that all the $b_i$ verifiy $b_i^p\in L_s$ and I don't see how to make that (but I know that $K(X)$ is purely inseparable over $L_s$ but it doesn't help me.)

Then I would need to continue with $L_s[b_1,b_2]$ but how to construct a purely transcendal extension $k(Z_1,\ldots,Z_q)$ over that $L_s[b_1,b_2]$ is finite separable?

Comment: Another proof: $\Omega^1_{K(X)/k}$ has $K)X)$-dimension $d$ by computing after extension to the perfect closure of $k$ (preserves topology -- irreducibility -- and reducedness by hypothesis), using existence of separating transcendence bases over perfect fields. Since $\Omega^1_{K(X)/k}$ is $K(X)$-spanned by elements ${\rm{d}}f$ for $f \in K(X)$, there is `$\{f_j\}$` so ${\rm{d}}f_j$'s are a $K(X)$-basis. The $f_j$'s are algebraically independent over the *perfect* $k$ (differentiate a potential *irreducible* relation) and $L=k(t_1,\dots,t_d)\rightarrow K(X)$ has $\Omega^1_{K(X)/L}=0$. QED